# Removing duplicates in two set using regex expression

Tags: java, set

I have two `HashSet<String>`:

```
Set<String> test = new HashSet<>();
test.add("LON/912");
test.add("LON/914");
test.add("LON/916");
```

and

```
Set<String> test1 = new HashSet<>();
test1.add("912");
```

I have compare the two Sets and remove the duplicate 912 from the test Set so the final set will be

```
[{LON/914},{LON/916}]
```

I don't want to use nested `for-loops` to compare as it is not performance efficient, can we achieve this using a `regex expression` or something else?

Comment: Sets do not contain duplicates. That is the definition of a set. Or are you saying you want to remove any elements that are present in both sets?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) to remove all elements that are present in another collection.

```
Set<String> first = new HashSet<>();
first.add("LON/912");
first.add("LON/914");

Set<String> second = new HashSet<>();
second.add("LON/912");

first.removeAll(second); // first now only contains "LON/912"
```

This would be good enough if your strings were completely equal but they are not. A simple fix would be to append "LON/" to every string that goes into the second set.

In case that is not possible, you'll have to be a bit more creative: You can add a separate class with a custom `equals` operator.

```
class MyString
{
    public String str;
    MyString(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        final MyString other = (MyString) obj;

        if (this.str.contains("LON/"))
        {
            return this.str.endsWith(other.str);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.str.equals(other.str);
        }
    }
}
```

and make a set of these:

```
Set<MyString> foo = new HashSet<>();
```

then use `removeAll` as I mentioned.

*Note the above implementation of the MyString class is only representative of what you need to implement. It's certainly not complete and should at the very least also contain a hashcode implementation.*

Comment: I guess OP's problem is that the string values are not really equal "LON/912" and just "912", so that won't work with the `removeAll` method. you need a custom comparator

Comment: @xander Yeah, I did notice that. I suspect it may be a typo but in case it's not I've added an extra bit to my answer.

Comment: maybe, but if that's a typo why does OP ask for a regex to compare the values, that makes no sense if the strings are equal, but who knows :D